# Custom delegate does not working in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, viewcontroller, uislider

My custom delegate does not work. Previously I used a custom delegate but this time it's not working. I want to pass data (`UISlider` value after change) from a `UIViewController` to a class that is subclass of `UIView`. Here is my code. Please help me out. -

RatingViewController.h -

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class StarRatingView; //define class, so protocol can see that class

@protocol DelegateForSlider <NSObject>   //define delegate protocol

- (void) getValue:(CGFloat) value;  //define delegate method to be implemented within another class

@end


@interface RatingViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <DelegateForSlider> delegate; //define DelegateForSlider as delegate
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *ratingView;
- (IBAction)sliderValueChange:(id)sender;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *slider;

@end
```

RatingViewController.m -

```
#import "RatingViewController.h"
#import "StarRatingView.h"

@interface RatingViewController ()

@end

@implementation RatingViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    StarRatingView* starViewWithAnimated = [[StarRatingView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 8, 100, 50) andRating:49];
    [self.ratingView addSubview:starViewWithAnimated];
}

- (IBAction)sliderValueChange:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Value Changed");
    [self.delegate getValue:self.slider.value];
}

@end
```

And In this class I want to get that `UISlider` value. 
StarRatingView.h -

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "RatingViewController.h"

@interface StarRatingView : UIView <DelegateForSlider>

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andRating:(int)rating;

@end
```

StarRatingView.m -

```
#import "StarRatingView.h"

@interface StarRatingView()

@property (strong, nonatomic) RatingViewController *ratingViewController;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel* label;

@end

@implementation StarRatingView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andRating:(int)rating {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        _ratingViewController.delegate = self;

        //Add label after star view to show rating as percentage
        self.label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,frame.size.width, frame.size.height)];
        self.label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18.0f];
        self.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%%",rating];
        self.label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
        self.label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        self.label.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        [self addSubview:self.label];
    }

    return self;
}

-(void) getValue:(CGFloat)value {
    NSLog(@"Got Value : %f", value);//This line does print nothing, I mean never fire
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the delegate in `RatingViewController.m`'s `viewDidLoad` method. The delegate isn't being set as is because when `initWithFrame:andRating:` is called, `_ratingViewController` is `nil`.

Also, it is bad practice to have a reference to a `UIViewController` in a `UIView`. Not only will it create a retain cycle, but it ignores half the reason of using delegates: to add the flexibility that any object that conforms to `DelegateForSlider` can be set to `StarRatingView`'s `delegate` property.

For more information on delegation check out [This programming overflow post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/190359/what-is-delegation-and-why-is-it-important-in-ios-programming) and [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html)

Comment: Thanks for your response. How it should be ? I tried but not works.

Comment: It looks like it should be `self.delegate = starViewWithAnimated`

Answer (score 0):

`_ratingViewController.delegate = self;`
ratingsViewController has no memory that it will set the delegate to self of this protocol.
Try this

```
_ratingsViewController = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
_ratingViewController.delegate = self;
```